# stationary independent increments: f(t+s) = f(t) + f(s), therefore f(t)=ct

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

[image: Stationary Independent Increments]

I don't get it... Why is the only solution to:

$$f(t+s) = f(t) + f(s)$$

equal to:

$$f(t) = ct$$

???

I have no idea how they came to this conclusion...

Comment: There is variable changing under improper integral in 3d line.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: To be pedantically correct, one ought to verify that $f$ is locally bounded or continuous or measurable, or something, to avoid  non-linear solutions to Cauchy's functional equation.

Comment: $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ has solution $f(x) = kx$ if f is continuous was a first year analysis problem sheet question when I saw it. Start with x, y as integers, then rationals then use continuity.

Answer (score 1):

$X(t)$ has stationary increments if $X(t)-X(s)$ has same distribution as $X(t-s)$ for $t-s>0$.

$X(t)$ has independent increments if for $t_n>\ldots>t_0$ if the increments $X(t_n)-X(t_{n-1}),\ldots,X(t_1)-X(t_0)$ have the same distribution.

Stationary independent increments are used in equation (5.123).

Let us suppose the function $f$ is continuous (not enough details given for that, but let us suppose this). A function that fulfills $f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(x)$ is said to be linear which probably is the part you missed.

In probabillity $f$ is deterministic but in statistics it is random when taking finite number of samples. Myself, I used to mess up possibly with statistics. In probability we get the same mean (the theoretical mean we get from intergration) everytime but in statistics we get always a random mean.

PS: Have a look at the difference between weak and strong stationarity.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, The part about the solution of the functional equation

$\bullet~$ **Lemma:** *The only non-constant continuous function $f$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying  functional equation*
$$ f(s + t) = f(s) + f(t) \quad \text{for any } s , t  \in \mathbb{R} $$
*is the linear function $f(x) = c x~$ for any $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and some $c$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.*

$\bullet~$ *Proof:* Plugin $s = t = 0$, we have
$$ f(0) = f(0) + f(0) \implies f(0) = 0 $$
Then plugin $s = t = x$, we have that
$$ f(2x) = 2f(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R} $$
Again, plugin $s = -t $, we have that
$$ f(0) = f(t) + f(- t) \implies f(-t) = -f(t) \quad \text{for any } t \in \mathbb{R} $$

---

---

$\bullet~$ **Claim:** *For any $n \in \mathbb{Q},$ $f(n) = c n$.*

$\bullet~$ *Proof:* Then we have a sub-claim

---

$\bullet \bullet~$ **Sub-Claim:** The function $f$ satisfies $$ f(kt) = kf(t) \quad \text{for any } t \in \mathbb{R} ~\text{ and any } k \in \mathbb{N} $$

$\bullet \bullet~$ *Proof:* The proof is straightforward by induction.

---

And we have that $f$ is an odd function. Then for any $n \in \mathbb{N},$ we have that
$$ f(-nt) = n f(-t) = -n f(t) \quad \text{for any } t \in \mathbb{R}  $$
Then we have that $f(k) = ck ~$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

The part of the proof of $\mathbb{Q},$ Is easy.

Hence we have that $f(t) = ct ~\text{ for any } t \in \mathbb{Q}$

---

---

$\bullet~$ **Claim:** The solution function $f(t) = ct~$ holds for any $t \not\in \mathbb{Q}$.

$\bullet~$ *Proof:* We can construct a sequence of rationals convergent to an irrational point.

So let's consider $\{x_{n} \}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $~x_{n} \to x~$ and $~x \not \in \mathbb{Q}.~$

Then we have that
\begin{align*}
&~f(x_{n}) = c x_{n} \quad\\
\implies & \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} cx_{n}\\
\implies & f\Big(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}\Big) = c \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} \quad \text{as } f \text{ is continuous on } \mathbb{R}]  \\
\implies & f(x) = cx  
\end{align*}
As $x \not \in \mathbb{Q} $ was arbitrary, hence we can say that $f(x) = cx ~$ for any $x \not \in \mathbb{Q}.$

---

---

Hence we have completed our proof of $f(x) = cx~$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, when $f$ is continuous.